# Access VB export certain query to designated filepath

Tags: vba, ms-access

So I have a query named `"the query I wish to export"`, I want to be able to export the query to Excel when I click the button on my form.

I created this function in `Module1` to call the dialog out and determine which file path I want to save my query result to.

```
Public Function ExportToExcel(strQuery As String)

    On Error GoTo Err_Handler

    Const MESSAGETEXT = "Overwrite existing file?"
    Dim OpenDlg As New BrowseForFileClass
    Dim strPath As String

    OpenDlg.DialogTitle = "Enter or Select File"
    strPath = OpenDlg.GetFileSpec
    Set OpenDlg = Nothing

    If strPath <> "" Then
        If Dir(strPath) <> "" Then
            If MsgBox(MESSAGETEXT, vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Confirm") = vbNo Then
                Exit Function
            Else
                Kill strPath
            End If
        End If
    Else
        Exit Function
    End If

    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, strQuery, strPath

Exit_Here:
    Exit Sub

Err_Handler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Here

End Function
```

After complete this function, I call this function and wish to export my query to the filepath that I wish to select.

```
Private Sub Export1_Click()

    Call Module1.ExportToExcel "the query I wish to export"

End Sub
```

It just keeps giving me *"Syntax Error"*. I don't really understand because I specifically call the function, passing the query name as its argument, any ideas?

Comment: I just did, and apparently, it's the '''Dim OpenDlg As New BrowseForFileClass''' that Access VB is not recognizing, any idea on which reference i should add in?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're evaluating the function using the [`Call`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/call-statement) keyword (which isn't strictly required), the arguments will need to be enclosed in parentheses, i.e.:

```
Call Module1.ExportToExcel("the query I wish to export")
```

---

For the file selection/specification, I would suggest using the [FileDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.filedialog) object, which will require a reference to the `Microsoft Office ##.0 Object Library`.

To provide an example of how this may be implemented, below is a quick function to demonstrate how you might go about prompting the user to specify/select an Excel file:

```
Function GetExcelFile(msg As String) As String
    Dim dia As FileDialog
    Set dia = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With dia
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = msg
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls; *.xlsx"
        If .show Then
            GetExcelFile = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Call the above with the desired dialog title, e.g.:

```
GetExcelFile "Enter or Select File"
```

The above will return an empty string if the user presses Cancel when prompted.

Comment: Great, this syntax is working but now, the module function is incorrect saying that "Can't find project or Library?